# How can I change "int" into "varchar" in mySQL database without problems in php code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, that I do not know how to solve. This is my code:

```
    $sql_current_animal = "SELECT orders.animal, farm.capacity  FROM orders LEFT JOIN farm ON orders.animal=farm.serial WHERE orders.id ='$id';";   
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql_current_animal) as $current_animal_row) {
        $current_animal = $current_animal_row['animal'];
        $capacity_animal_arr[$current_animal] = $current_animal_row['capacity'];
    }
```

The type of `capacity`was in my database `int(11)`. When it was like that my code worked very well. But now I need to change the type of `capacity` to `varchar(225)`. I still have the same value of `capacity` in my database (for example: `2`), but my code is not working anymore. What exactly happens is, everything is displayed on my page to this line and after this my page is blank.

The problem must be in this line: `$capacity_animal_arr[$current_animal] = $current_animal_row['capacity'];` because when I delete this line, everything is displayed on the page again.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the rest of your script expects `capacity` to be of type Integer. Try converting the value in PHP to int. Here's how:

```
$capacity_animal_arr[$current_animal] = intval($current_animal_row['capacity']);
```

Please confirm if it works for you.

Comment: It is working with your code! Thank you :) I am just wondering, later I need longer numbers like `21990232555520` is this also working with `intval`?

Comment: If you're using a 64 bit system, then the maximum you can go is:  9223372036854775807. On a 32 bit system, the maximum is:  2147483647

Answer (score 0):

Firstly echo the value of $current_animal_row['capacity'] and $current_animal_row['animal'] before line $capacity_animal_arr[$current_animal] = $current_animal_row['capacity'].If you will get correct value of capacity and animal then problem is not from db.

Comment: Hello, thank you. `$current_animal_row['capacity'] ` echoes `2` and `$current_animal_row['animal'] ` echoes `elephant`.